# Reuse node removed from DOM

Tags: javascript

I've been struggling with this issue for the last couple of hours now and have decided to come to stackoverflow for this.

I want to clear all of the elements in the body tag, except 1 (this includes it's children).

So what I thought I'd do is.
1. Store the element in a variable.
2. Clear the body tag.
3. Re-add the stored element.

However, the developer console gives me the following error.

```
Uncaught NotFoundError: An attempt was made to reference a Node in a context where it does not exist.
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Also, I'm not using jQuery or any other framework, so native JavaScript would be appreciated.

```
var myBody = null;

var myNode = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
while(myNode.lastChild) {
if(myNode.lastChild.id !== "c_container") {
    myNode.removeChild(myNode.lastChild);
}else{
    myBody = myNode.removeChild(myNode.lastChild);
}
}

myNode.appendChild(myBody);
```

HTML only the parts which matter to the subject:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="left_container">
            <div id="c_container">
                <!-- content -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The actual code involved would be quite helpful.

Comment: How do you clear the body tag? Please include a [minimal code demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What browser are you using?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include the code. Don't come on here all too often to ask questions. I'm using Maxthon. The code also completely erases everything. My guess is it's because it's nested in another child element of the body tag.

Comment: You're probably only storing a reference to the the element, which you're deleting afterwards.

Comment: So how would I store the actual object itself then Jonathan?

Comment: You could store the outerHTML for instance.

Comment: please show the html as well, the code works (in chrome at least) if `c_container` is a child of body.

Comment: [Your code works fine for me in Firefox.](http://jsfiddle.net/9ufyv/)

Comment: Here's an article about removing a childnode and keeping it for further purposes: [node.removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild)

Comment: @Jonathan there should be no need to do that.

Comment: Then my guess is that it is indeed because `c_container` is not a direct child of `body`. Would moving the element in the DOM structure to be a direct element of body before doing the deletion help?

Comment: @Tohveli that is what I'm doing.

Comment: @ShadowParallax: Please include your HTML markup. If `c_container` really is no direct child of the `myBody`, your code must not work, because the node can never be `myBody.lastChild`. Btw, did you confuse `myNode` (which refers to the `body`) with `myBody` (which refers to the `#c_container`) in your code?

Comment: @Pointy seems you're right. My mistake.

Comment: @Bergi no that was on purpose, as I'm making this for a profile page but want to remove the default HTML markup. So `myBody` would refer to my body markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just get the element you want to save by id. Then clear the body by setting its content to `""` and then appending the saved element. No need to loop and remove nodes individually.

```
var ele = document.getElementById("c_container");
document.body.innerHTML = "";
document.body.appendChild(ele);
```

[jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fWC4g/)

Comment: Boy do I feel stupid. I had attempted something like that before looping through the elements. Except I retrieved the body tag with `getElementsByTagName`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code worked when I tried it [in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ufyv/) but not for you is that your "c_container" element is *inside* an element that your code will remove. The string of node children is just the level of the DOM tree immediately beneath the starting point (the body, in your case).  Your loop will only go for one iteration, removing that wrapper `<div>` element. It'll never see your "c_container" because it's not a direct child of the `<body>` tag.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected something like that. Thanks for your support. :)

Comment: …and then yield an erratic error message when `myBody` is unexpectedly `undefined` when trying to append it. What else did we expect from trident?!